# Presence and spoiled snacks on Purim?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

This morning after davening I was struck by the congregation breaking out into song:

> Misha nichnas our door, mar bamba simcha!

I looked around the room but was unable to identify the new member of the minyan. Upon further reflection, this verse poses a number of conundrums:

- Who is this Misha?
- Why is it critical that Misha enter through the door and not, for example, the window or a skylight?
- Why would their presence transform the consumption of a normally disappointing [bag of peanut puffs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamba_(snack)) into a joyous occasion?

**This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).**

Comment: Why would Misha enter through the window?

Comment: @Daniel "Ki Alah Misha BiChaloneinu?" We see Hillel using the skylight, but let's say the shul was too tall for him to get up to the roof - the window would be the next logical choice.

Comment: Curious, what is the actual song being parodied here?

Comment: @SAH Mishenichnas Adar Marbim Bisimcha